# match 2 columns of 1 sheet with 2 columns of another sheet to return a value from second sheet using python

Tags: python, match

I am stuck a bit here. The given charts are something like this:

Sheet_1:

```
Col1    Col2    Value1
A   E   
B   F   
C   G   
D   H   
….. ….  ….
```

Sheet_2:

```
Col3    Col4    Value2
D   H   2
B   F   5
A   E   6
X   Y   8
….. ….  ….
```

How can I match col1 and col2 of sheet_1 with col3 and col 4 of sheet_2, and if it gets a perfect match, it will take the value from value2 column and place it in the respective row of value1 column?
Is it possible in python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read second table line-by line, split the lines into columns and then create a dictionary which has the first two columns as key and the rest as value. Then you can look up the value for any column1,columns2 pair in that dictionary.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code for this kind of task? @zvone

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Prune gave a good comment. In this particular case, I would suggest that you split the task into parts, e.g. first part is _"Read second table line-by line"_. If you don't know how to do that, google _"how to read a file line by line in python"_. You will find many answers. Try them. If they don't work, google the problem which happens, repeat until there is no answer available and if you are still stuck, then ask a question about that part, which will be more specific. Do the same for the other steps.